# Do the Scientific Miracles in the Qur'an actually exist?

Tags: quran

Scientific miracles in Quran are those facts told by the quran and later discovered by science , For example:

> The word month exists 12 times in the quran, the word day 365....

But this article actually refutes many of these miracles: [Arabic](http://www.m.ahewar.org/s.asp?aid=392620&r=0).

> But it is true that the word "month" is  reported four times only and twenty in total, if you include the words months or monthly. The word day is reported 217 not 365.

. I know from this question: [Scientific conflicts with respect to Quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5752/scientific-conflicts-with-respect-to-quran)
that sometimes quran is just misinterpreted with respect to science. But if we were unable to interpret quran in a complete way does this mean that scientific miracles in quran weren't meant to be present at all? Is quran meant to be scientific, if it was why can't we find at least one scientific miracle in the quran?

Comment: instead of claim. please select one conflict and explain exactly how it conflict Quran. a general claim needs writing a book to answer. any claim is not true. there are many lies and mirage.

Comment: I wonder, if number of occurrence of the word _day_ is 365, why it is called a miracle. Our [islamic calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) consists of 354 days, not 365.

Comment: Actually the example you bring here is not proper at all, months being 12 in number is announced in " إِنَّ عِدَّةَ الشُّهُورِ‌ عِندَ اللَّـهِ اثْنَا عَشَرَ‌ شَهْرً‌ا فِي كِتَابِ اللَّـهِ يَوْمَ خَلَقَ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْ‌ضَ مِنْهَا أَرْ‌بَعَةٌ حُرُ‌مٌ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ الدِّينُ الْقَيِّمُ" in [9:36], the difference of number of days in a lunar and solar year being 11 is denoted in "وَلَبِثُوا فِي كَهْفِهِمْ ثَلَاثَ مِائَةٍ سِنِينَ وَازْدَادُوا تِسْعًا" in [18:25]. But these are not scientific miracles at least to my eyes. You could instead, e.g. point to Islam's view on dark matter ... (7 skies)

Comment: what you mean by this example? you seek some scientific miracles from Quran? or you want to refute a specific claim of miracle about Quran? it is possible that some claims of miracles about Quran are not correct. this does not mean Quran has error. sometimes people understand Quran wrong. but still there are many scientific miracles in Quran. if an understanding of Quran is correct or not can be determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know whether number of occurrences is a basis of information or not, but we all know that direct declarations are.

[Muhammad said](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/8) :***The year is of twelve months***. 
 So Islam stands correct regarding the fact that a year consists of 12 months, no matter how many times it occur in Quran.

There are circulation of **scientific conflicts** on the web, most of which are recorded in wikiislam, which are either misunderstanding or deliberate misinterpretation by them.

But there are indeed some verses which science donot agree with.

[One of such verses](http://quran.com/2/29) that scientists don't agree with is the presence of seven heavens. But, after all the claims that science makes, here is the Hilarious statement:

> All the stars, planets and galaxies that can be seen today make up just 4 percent of the universe. The other 96 percent is made of stuff astronomers can't see, detect or **even comprehend**. ([source](http://www.space.com/11642-dark-matter-dark-energy-4-percent-universe-panek.html))

Now naturally a question comes to our mind: **Given that science is still donot know half of the universe, how can we say that these *conflicting verses* are false?**

And what about the other verses that are established as truth? To mention a few, see [this](http://www.miraclesofthequran.com/scientific_106.html), [this](http://www.miraclesofthequran.com/scientific_20.html) and [this](http://www.miraclesofthequran.com/scientific_50.html) of the same site. All of them are true.

To answer your last question, **No , Quran was not meant to be scientific**. Here is how Quran define itself in [14:52](http://quran.com/14/52):

> This [Qur'an] is notification for the people that they may be warned thereby and that they may know that He is but one God and that those of understanding will be reminded.

But it contains some universal truth to indicate that it is indeed from God, some which scientists have already experimentally found out to be true.

Comment: Quran has clarification for all things: http://tanzil.net/#16:89 and http://tanzil.net/#6:59 everything includes science too. if you do not have the scientific knowledge of Quran do not say it is not in Quran. only say I do not know. http://tanzil.net/#17:36  and 14:52 does not say Quran is ONLY for notification.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala ,  you are right. but i think quran was not meant to be a scientific thesis, rather it is a guidance for people. but it contains some facts which are already proven and others are yet to be proved.

Answer (score 0):

In our daily life, we get to pass through 2 types of stuff!

1. **Scientific**
2. **Religious**

The type where science is the subject, there you need a proof, you prove that water is composed of 2 hydrogen atoms, and one oxygen atom. But religion is entirely opposite. In religion you give logics! You have no formula to prove the existence of Allah Almighty, you give logics of the existence. And that's what differs Science to Religion.

What you're saying, might be true as I am not Hafiz (sadly) so I cannot say whether these words were used in this quantity or not. But, I can tell you! This has nothing to do with the Science, Quran was revealed on Holy Prophet (PBUH) about 1500 years ago, however the Christian Calender (Gregorian) is more than 2014 years ago, the calender we use! So, they have the same number of months in it. Days are also the same, so this isn't the way Quran deals with daily life.

Quran, has everything in it, Quran is the book, which can be asked for help in every situation! You will find the solution very easily only if you read and understand it carefully! Otherwise you'll get the same result, **month** word being used 12 times and **day** word being used 30 times.

#### We cannot find any scientific miracle?

Miracles are not scientific, they are Holy! Moses' stick turned into a great snake, science can't do that! It was a miracle. You are just mixing up the Science with Religion. Try to remember, what is in the Religion, can never be found in Science! To be simple, you can say that Religion is the Universe and the science is our planet earth, or maybe your country; which ever you live in. Science is nothing in front of the knowledge and information Religion gives us.

Quran told Muslims about the future! Science can't do that. Quran told us, that there will be a time, when a group of Muslims will be the cause of terror! You can see that in the time today. Quran told Holy Prophet about the Big buildings, Motor cars etc!

If you, yourself read the Quran sometime. You will notice that the real knowledge is kept in Quran rather than in Quantum of Physics or the Chemistry of Organic Compounds or in the Complete Biology for GCSE! Science cannot stand in front of Religion, and there fore we cannot match the Miracles with Scientific researches!

Comment: By scientific miracles I meant scientific discoveries stated by quran once and now they are approved by science.

Comment: Oh hehe, I am sorry! I misunderstood! and I have stated that Quran has told you everything a long time ago! :)

Comment: Afzaal Ahmad Zeeshan, then tell me why should I believe the miracles of Islam and not the miracles of the Mormons or Buddhists or Aztecs or Mayans or Incas.

Comment: @user5434 did I say you should reject those? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a couple of Sciences that the Quran mentions before science has discovered them.

> 2.26 Surely Allah is not ashamed to set forth any parable– (that of) a mosquito or any thing above that; then as for those who believe, they
>   know that it is the truth from their Lord, and as for those who
>   disbelieve, they say: What is it that Allah means by this parable: He
>   causes many to err by it and many He leads aright by it! but He does
>   not cause to err by it (any) except the transgressors.

Where does Allah give a parable of a mosquito in the Quran?

The preceding verses explain how mosquitos are attracted to light. When you read the ayahs with the mosquito involved and how they react to light.

**READ IT WITH A LIFE OF MOSQUITO rather than a human example.
Listen carefully.....**

> 2.17 Their parable is like the parable of one who kindled a fire,  but when it had illumined all around him,  Allah took away their light, 
>   and left them in utter darkness– they do not see.
>
> 2.20 The lightning almost takes away their sight;  whenever it shines on them they walk in it,  and when it becomes dark to them they stand
>   still;  and if Allah had pleased He would certainly have taken away
>   their hearing and their sight;  surely Allah has power over all
>   things.

+++++
There is one unidentified possible scientific importance to this parable as well. It comes with the in between ayahs.

> 2.18-19 Deaf, dumb (and) blind,  so they will not turn back. Or like abundant rain from the cloud in which is utter darkness and thunder
>   and lightning;  they put their fingers into their ears because of the
>   thunder peal,  for fear of death, and Allah encompasses the
>   unbelievers

Mosquitos have what is called ”Positive phototaxis” (Movement towards a light source by organisms)It helps the mosquitos receive light for photosynthesis process.

> 2.18 Deaf, dumb (and) **blind**

With light they see.
Blind/Seeing can be explained

With the use of the light's energy, They perform an intelligent extremely beneficial action.

> 2.18 Deaf, **dumb** (and) blind
>   Dumb/intellect explained

BUT the Quran also states “**Deaf**”!!!!

Mosquitos tympanal organs (its “ears”) are located on its antennae (on other insects could be quite literally everywhere).

They are located at base of the antennae and known as the Johnston’s organ (a collection of sensory cells).

It’s has been recorded to be sensitive to sounds up to 2000Hz

**Quran is saying light potentially makes sound at an atomic level;
That is beyond our hearing capability frequency (after all possess an oscillatory nature.)**

"Sound" is a mechanical phenomenon, light is electromagnetic, but it possesses mass (just no rest-mass), and as such has kinetic energy. This energy imparted to other atoms could possibly make a sound.

Our increase of technology advances hopefully could prove this point but for the time being, it remains a unprovable theory from science, not from theology

Your turn science.﻿ ;)